# Angular JS call function from template which doesn't belong to the scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This might sound odd, but I have a repeater which looks like this.

```
<tr ng-repeat="task in tasks">
    <td>{{getFriendlyDate(date)}}</td>
</tr>
```

I can put this function on the scope like this.

```
$scope.getFriendlyDate = function(date){

    /* Code to convert ISO date to readable date */
    return date;

};
```

That works fine, but I need to use this function in lots of templates so I don't want to have to copy and paste it into lots of controllers.

One option is to create a service to do this and put a simple wrapper on the scope in each controller, but that's not going to save me much time.

Another option is to put the function on the root scope and access it directly in my templates, but I'd prefer it to live in my utilities library (I have a $utils library created using a factory).

I'm wondering if it's possible to call a service to do the date conversion directly from the template?

Comment: You could try making a custom angular directive similar to what's described here: http://www.befundoo.com/university/tutorials/angularjs-directives-tutorial/.

Comment: I guess I could, but creating  directive seems like overkill.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want a filter. Create the filter once:

```
angular.module("myModule").filter('friendlyDate', function() {
     return function(date) {
          /* Code to convert ISO date to readable date */
          return date;
     };
});
```

And then in your HTML everywhere:

```
<tr ng-repeat="task in tasks">
    <td>{{date | friendlyDate}}</td>
</tr>
```